# Angular Directive Post Link Order Is Wrong (1.3)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a situation where I have two nested custom directives. Normally the post link functions are fired in reverse order, but in my particular case they are firing top down, which is prohibiting my ability to modify the DOM reliably. I have tried to recreate the issue in a Plunker but it always correct so I am absolutely stumped!

`<message-container> <------ The template for this directive contains the directive <scrollable-content>
</message-container>`

#### Scrollable-Content

`return {
                restrict: 'E',
                templateUrl: 'core/app/partials/common/scrollable.html',
                transclude: true,
                replace: true,
                scope: true,
                link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {....`

#### Message-Container

`return {
                restrict: 'E',
                replace: true,
                scope: true,
                templateUrl: 'core/app/partials/chat/message-container.html',
                link: function ($scope, $element) {....`

Since I cant reproduce this with any other directives or in a plunker, does anyone know of any reason how or why this could occur? Basically in my linking function for the message-container I want to add some event listeners in the scrollable content directive markup. The element in the link function for message list just has the mark-up of  and not the compiled content.

Any help is appreciated!

## ***UPDATE: Our templates are pre cached***

Comment: Are you using element.bind in the top level directive to bind those events?

Comment: We aren . Its really stumped us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few months ago I dove into this, it seemed wrong.But there is actually logic behind this.
templateUrl download the template async, and triggers a compile for those nodes  after the template comes back. This will even work this way if you use cached the templates. The "loading" of the tempateURL will be done after the current digest cycle is ready. Indeed even if the template is already in the `$tempateCache`
There was some discussion about this, and [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#templateUrl) was adapted to put some emphasis on this behavior.

If you really need the order, use static templates.
Or use a trick like this:

```
 template: $templateCache.get('myTemplate.html'),
```

Of coarse you need to pre-load your template to make this work!

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that our templates are pre cached so there are no async requests

Comment: That makes no difference in this situation. The upside is that you can use the trick I showed you without any more adaptations.

Comment: I see. I'll give this a try and report back. Thanks.

Comment: This has fixed the issue. Thanks very much for your help!